# Tag suggestion/inquiry

Tags: discussion, tags

Are there tags to specify that a language is for fiction the asker is writing as opposed to an "official" language (esperanto for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Such conlangs are sometimes called "artlangs" - we don't have a tag for that currently, but it could be appropriate.

The [design-goals](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-goals) tag could also be appropriate, depending on the question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what curiousdannii mentioned, it should be noted that we currently have specific tags for established conlangs (e.g., [esperanto](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esperanto), [lojban](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lojban), [toki-pona](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toki-pona),[tolkien-elvish](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkien-elvish), etc.) rather than having a separate tag for questions that are relevant to a user's own conlanging. Those questions can be far more varied than questions about popular existing conlangs and should be tagged for other properties of the question (e.g., using [design-goals](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-goals) for questions regarding how to achieve particular purposes in one's own conlang, using [naturalism](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naturalism) for questions about whether features one plans on including in one's conlang are naturalistic, etc.).